# Why doesn't message.content.startswith work?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to get this code to work but it just wont work. I'm stumped on how to get this to work.

The entirety of my code:

```
import discord



intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
            return
    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        print("testing")
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
```

Trying to make it detected when "$hello" is said and respond with "Hello"

Comment: Print out `message.content` (or check it with a debugger). `startswith` works fine, so that suggests the data isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.users:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("$hello"):
        print(message.content)
        await message.channel.send("Hello!")
```

the section of `if message.author == client.users:` is likely causing the issue, because `client.users` is referencing a list of all users the client can see, but not the user who sent the message. so you could need need to remove the `s` at the end of `users`

```py
if message.author == client.users:
```

is checking if the author of the bot is the bot itself.

EDIT: After messing around with your code, i changed the `discord.Intents.default()` to .all() instead as well.